# How to detect when any file is being attached/uploaded to an email client or email in web browser in C#?

Tags: c#, file, email, pdf, email-attachments

When any file is attached to email in browser or any email client, how to detect the event? What is the process running in windows or browser when the file is being attached? In other words what is the process for uploading of files? How to detect that process from c# code? Is there any way to detect this event or process using FileSystemWatcher?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? (i.e why do you care if a file is uploaded?)

Comment: I want to track and log to database whenever a file is being attached/uploaded to any email client or email in web browser(like gmail,yahoomail).

Comment: If you're worried about corporate security, you could look at monitoring the gateways as well as looking at NTFS auditing - both are far too large a subject to cover as an answer here (and may be more relevant on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com)

Answer (score 2):

Simply speaking, there is not. All uploading a file does is open it,so the best you could do in theory is find the process that was opening the file and use heuristics. However FileSystemWatcher is for monitoring changes to files, and the closest you could get to finding out which process was opening a file would be constantly polling it's status using the external tool handle.exe in C#, or NtQuerySystemInformation in C++.

Comment: I cannot poll a particular file. I want to detect and log to database as a file attach event whenever any pdf file is being attached to email

Comment: That's why I said there really isn't a way, I was just providing some theoretical ways to "hack it" for one file, but in general what you want to do is impossible, even the the OS service for File Auditing wouldn't be able to tell when a file was being used as an email attachment. Maybe you could write some kind of system to capture the content of unencrypted emails to get the mime type and recognize them being sent _after the fact_, or write a browser plugin to do something similar, but in general, it's really not possible. If this is meant to prevent uploads for enterprise, look at Outlook.