# Is it possible to get handle of address bar in open file dialog using c# window handle?

Tags: c#, window-handles

I need to retrieve address if user is selecting a file for email attachment. is there any way to use window handle to get handle of address bar of open file dialog?

Comment: from javascript? NO WAY.

Comment: @GeorgeLica Who talks about js?

Comment: Then he should be more specific ... in what environment the user selects a file? (from browser, from a windows forms app, etc).

Comment: @George Lica Thanks for your reply.. My requirement is to capture the file if the user try to attach in email. im using c#

Answer (score -1):

The following link provides the PInvoke mechanism for calling the Windows GetWindowText which allows you to read the title text of another window.

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getwindowtext

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.. My requirement is to capture the file if the user try to attach in email. im using c#. is it possible to capture it??

Comment: Capture the file, or capture the file name ? Your question was about capturing the file name - not the file itself. I see your comment to someone elses question and its clear you want to capture the File not the File Name. In which case its entirely dependent on which email program your user is using - Outlook, Windows Mail, a Web Mail program of some kind ? Edit your original question to make this clearer please.

Comment: Ok - then no. Your original question said "is there any way to use window handle to get handle of address bar of open file dialog" which I think I answered - however the File Open dialog box doesn't normally contain the name of the file being selected - only the folder currently highlighted.

Comment: Thanks.. is there a way to capture filename if a user try to attach in email in browser (Any mail). I found some reference to use window handle. so i posted this question.

Comment: reference thread [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24968932/how-to-detect-when-any-file-is-being-attached-uploaded-to-an-email-client-or-ema)

Comment: I cant see any refernce to Window Handle in that thread. It doesnt matter; the answers in your linked thread are still the same; however if you really want to do this you need to go deep down into OS File System Filter Hooks as explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109564/intercept-windows-open-file